# Can a hostname be added to syslog-ng?

Tags: hostname, syslog

How can syslog-ng be configured to send both the hostname and the IP address. Currently, logs are sent with the IP address of the device/machine, but we want to add the hostname so I could keep my ip management database up to date with the correct hostname (no, I don't use DHCP :))